# iOS - Highlight lines in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uitextview

I'm trying to achieve the same effect as we have in programming IDEs.
[image]
With only exception that I need to be able to dynamically highlight and un-highlight multiple lines by their numbers. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Make an attempt and come back here with specific questions about what you've tried, what works, and what doesn't.

Comment: check this https://gist.github.com/onmyway133/c1fb7f8bf26a0bd144a3

Comment: @Stonz2 I know about stackoverflow best practices in question. I didn't put anything in question becuase I didn't have any success. I've tried to realize how to get range of line by its number but google told me nothing. That's only thing that came to my mind